# Xamarin Android RecyclerView 2 строки в одной ячейке, программное создание RecyclerView

Tags: recyclerview, xamarin.android

Суть моего вопроса заключается в том, чтобы можно было, например как в почтовом клиенте, в одну ячейку поместить 2 строчки одна под другую и при этом они могут иметь разные параметры (шрифт, цвет, отступ и тд). 
При этом чтобы RecyclerView создавался программно, так как нужно, чтобы всё происходило на одном слое. 
    Например нажал на кнопку, слой затирается и на него кладутся вновь созданные элементы.

Вот основа моих опытов:  Есть код простенького RecyclerView

```
 using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;

namespace recyclerview
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            string[] items;



            public MyAdapter(string[] data)
            {
                items = data;

            }

            // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                //    set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
                var tv = new TextView(parent.Context);
                tv.SetHeight(200);
                tv.Text = "";


                var vh = new MyViewHolder(tv);
                return vh;
            }

            // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
            {
                var item = items[position];

                // Replace the contents of the view with that element
                var holder = viewHolder as MyViewHolder;
                holder.TextView.Text = items[position];

            }



            public override int ItemCount
            {
                get
                {
                    return items.Length;
                }
            }
        }
        public class MyViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView TextView { get; set; }


            public MyViewHolder(TextView v) : base(v)
            {
                TextView = v;

            }
        }

        //MyAdapter mAdapter;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            RecyclerView TaskList;
           // TaskList = new RecyclerView(this);
          //  LinearLayout lin = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearall);
           // TaskList.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            TaskList =  FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
           // lin.AddView(TaskList);

            // Plug in the linear layout manager:
            var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this) { Orientation = LinearLayoutManager.Vertical };
            TaskList.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            TaskList.HasFixedSize = true;

            //    var recyclerViewData = GetData(Lister);
            string[] recyclerViewData = new string[] { "odin", "dva", "tri" };

            // Plug in my adapter:
            MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(recyclerViewData);
            TaskList.SetAdapter(mAdapter);



        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

и есть такой вот axml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id ="@+id/linearall">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height ="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id = "@+id/recyclerView"

 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Подскажите куда копать, что нажимать

Comment: Ваш вопрос тяжело читается (много лишних слов) Уберите "лирику" из вопроса и оставите, только то, что нужно для дела. Гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам разобрался в основном благодаря вот этой статье на java https://metanit.com/java/android/5.11.php Вот рабочий код

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;

namespace recyclerview
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public class data
        {
            public string text1 { get; set; }
            public string text2 { get; set; }
            public data(string text1,string text2)
            {
                this.text1 = text1;
                this.text2 = text2;
            }
        }
        public class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
           public List<data> dataall;
            public LayoutInflater inflater;



            public MyAdapter(Context context,List<data> datacome )
            {
                dataall = datacome;
                this.inflater = LayoutInflater.From(context);

            }

            // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {

                View tv = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_item,parent,false);


                var vh = new MyViewHolder(tv);
                return vh;
            }

            // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
            {
                 data dataone = dataall[position];

                // Replace the contents of the view with that element
                var holder = viewHolder as MyViewHolder;
                holder.data1.Text = dataone.text1;
                holder.data2.Text = dataone.text2;


            }



            public override int ItemCount
            {
                get
                {
                    return dataall.Count;
                }
            }
        }
        public class MyViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView data1 { get; set; }
            public TextView data2 { get; set; }

            public MyViewHolder(View v) : base(v)
            {

                data1 = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.data1);
                data2 = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.data2);

            }
        }

        //MyAdapter mAdapter;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            RecyclerView TaskList;
           // TaskList = new RecyclerView(this);
          //  LinearLayout lin = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearall);
           // TaskList.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            TaskList =  FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
           // lin.AddView(TaskList);

            // Plug in the linear layout manager:
            var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this) { Orientation = LinearLayoutManager.Vertical };
            TaskList.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            TaskList.HasFixedSize = true;

            //    var recyclerViewData = GetData(Lister);

            List<data> phones = new List<data>();
            setInitialData();
            // Plug in my adapter:
            MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, phones);
            TaskList.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

             void setInitialData()
            {

                phones.Add(new data("Huawei P10", "Huawei"));
                phones.Add(new data("Elite z3", "HP"));
                phones.Add(new data("Galaxy S8", "Samsung"));
                phones.Add(new data("LG G 5", "LG"));
            }

        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

так же к нему нужно создать еще 1 слой list_item.axml с таким вот кодом

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```